# How to serialize an abstract class in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, serialization

I have an abstract model class that has an abstract function that determines how a widget switches state and I would like to keep it.
I am currently trying to implement https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable but it wants me to switch the field type to a dynamic type instead of my abstract one. You cant @JsonSerializeable abstract classes and when I switch to a dynamic type the print reads as Instance of 'class' even when the concrete implementations have a valid toJson method.

Should I just throw out OOP principle implementation or is there an alternative solution here?

Answer (score 1):

```
    <String, dynamic>{
      'command': instance.command,
      'questions': instance.questions.map((e) {return (e as Question).toJson();}).toList(),
    };
```

Solved by writing my own serializer for my abstract class